# how filter json python element

Tags: python, json

I have a json that I have via a python request, and I need to check if the "extension" key is equal to "txt", if so give a message.

```
from requests import get
import json

url = get('http://', auth = ('user', 'password'))

data_JSON = url.json()

for element in json['diffs']:
    if element['extension'] == 'txt':
        print ("have txt")
```

The json that returns from the request is this:

```
{
   "fromHash":"***",
   "toHash":"BG",
   "contextLines":10,
   "whitespace":"SHOW",
   "diffs":[
      {
         "source":{
            "components":[
               "arquivo1.txt"
            ],
            "parent":"",
            "name":"arquivo1.txt",
            "extension":"txt",
            "toString":"arquivo1.txt"
         },
```

....

I want to check the extension key if the value is txt, if yes return a message

Comment: `any(el["source"]["extension"] == "txt" for el in data_JSON["diffs"])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need to use a for loop to iterate over "diffs".
Simply use an index such as `0`.

Take a look at the following data which represents your JSON structure.

```
sample_json = {
    "diffs":[
        {
        "source":{
            "extension":"txt",
        }
        }
    ]
}
```

It appears, our first key is called diffs which has a list value.
We can easily access the diffs list by using `sample_json["diffs"]`; This returns a list.

So we index it -> `sample_json["diffs"][0]`

We get a dictionary (go to source) ->  `sample_json["diffs"][0]["source"]`

Look for the extensions key -> `sample_json["diffs"][0]["source"]["extensions"]`

I've given you an explanation so that later on in the future you can follow a similar process.

code

```
sample_json = {
    "diffs":[
        {
        "source":{
            "extension":"txt",
        }
        }
    ]
}
extension = sample_json["diffs"][0]["source"]["extension"]
if extension == "txt":
    print("true")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I managed to solve it that way before seeing your answer:

from requests import get
import json

url = get('http://', auth = ('user', 'password'))

data_JSON = url.json()

data_JSON = data_JSON['diffs'][0]['source']
if (data_JSON['extension']) == 'txt':

 print (data_JSON['extension'])
 
print ("have txt")

Answer (score 1):

Use `element['source']['extension']` instead of `element['extension']` since `extension` is a key within `element['source']` not `element` directly.

```py
from requests import get
import json

url = get('http://', auth = ('user', 'password'))

data_JSON = url.json()
for element in data_JSON['diffs']:
    if element['source']['extension'] == 'txt':
        print('have txt')
```